# SSH client on Ubuntu 15.10 is not working with public key

Tags: server, ssh, authentication, openssh

I am trying to `ssh` from my Ubuntu machine to other SSH servers, and also to itself but it is not working with the public key - it always prompts for a password.

verbose output from `ssh` client

```
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/jruocco/.ssh/id_rsa
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp SHA256:d4AIC3wwR5k2NubCySUxj8Hreru3QErMM9+8pdKcO4g
debug1: Trying private key: /home/jruocco/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/jruocco/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/jruocco/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: password
jruocco@10.1.1.4's password:
```

debug information from `/usr/sbin/sshd -d`

```
debug1: trying public key file /home/jruocco/.ssh/authorized_keys
debug1: fd 4 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: matching key found: file /home/jruocco/.ssh/authorized_keys, line 1 RSA SHA256:d4AIC3wwR5k2NubCySUxj8Hreru3QErMM9+8pdKcO4g
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
Postponed publickey for jruocco from 127.0.0.1 port 35666 ssh2 [preauth]
```

I should mention that I can authenticate using public key from another linux machine (Kali) to this computer no problem.

```
[ubuntu] > [ubuntu] = failing
[kali]   > [ubuntu] = working
```

Comment: please, post verbose log with `-vvv` and server log with `-ddd` switches.. It will tell you more.

Comment: I created a DSA key and it worked right away. I will get you the outputs of the verbose and debug switches shortly.